# MVC4 with Telerik Editor not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik

For some reason my Telerik MVC Editor() is not working.  Can anyone spot what I´m doing wrong?

*I´m using MVC4 with Razor view engine and Telerik version 2012.1.214*

**_Layout.cshtml includes this:**

```
@using Smekklegt.Models
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="is" xml:lang="is">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/AjaxLogin.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<!-- Skrár frá template-->
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/rikona/styles/galleriffic.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/rikona/style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/rikona/js/jquery-1.3.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/rikona/js/jquery.opacityrollover.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/rikona/js/jquery.galleriffic.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/rikona/js/gallery-settings.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--[if IE 6]>
        <script src="../../Content/rikona/js/ie6-transparency.js"></script>
        <script>
            DD_belatedPNG.fix('#header .logo img, .subtitle img, .slideshow-container, .navigation-container #thumbs .thumbs li .thumb img, .navigation a.next, .footer-line, #sidebar .author-photo, .line, .commentlist .comment-reply-link, #contact-page #contact .submit');
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/rikona/styles/ie6.css" />
    <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/rikona/styles/ie7.css" />
    <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/rikona/styles/ie8.css" />
    <![endif]-->
@(Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar()
                  .DefaultGroup(group => group
                      .Add("telerik.common.css")
                      .Add("telerik.simple.css")
                      .Combined(true)
                      .Compress(true))
                 )
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
        <section id="login" style="float: right;">
            @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
        </section>
        <section style="float: left;">
            <ul>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Flokkar", "Index", "Category")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Vörur", "Index", "Product")</li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="../../Content/rikona/images/smekklegt_banner2.jpg" alt="logo" width="400px;" />
        </div>
        <div id="nav">                
            <ul id="nav-pages">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Forsíða", "Index", "Home")<span>|</span></li>
                @foreach (Category category in (IEnumerable<Category>)ViewData["Categories"])
                {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(category.Name, "FindProductsByCategory", "Product", new { catId = category.Id }, null)<span>|</span></li>
                }
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("smekklegt.is", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="frontpage-content">
        <div id="container">
            @RenderSection("featured", false)
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer" style="margin-top: 15px;">
        <div class="footer-line">
        </div>
            <p>
                &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year Smekklegt ehf</p>
        <div class="float-right">
            <ul id="social">
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sersaumadir.smekkir" target="_blank" class="facebook">Facebook</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    @Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false).DefaultGroup(g => g.Combined(true).Compress(true))
</div>
```

**Create.cshtml includes this:**

```
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI
@model Smekklegt.Controllers.ProductFormViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Product</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.FK_Category)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.FK_Category)*@
        @Html.DropDownListFor(d => d.Categories, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Name"))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.FK_Category)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.Description)
    </div>

    <div>
        @{ Html.Telerik().EditorFor(m => m.Product.Description)
               .Name("ProductCreateEditor")
               .Encode(false)
               .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 500px;" })
               .Tools(t => t.Clear()
               .Bold().Italic().Underline().Separator().JustifyCenter().JustifyLeft().JustifyRight().JustifyFull())
               //.Value((string)ViewData["ProductDescription"])
               .Render(); }
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Stofna" />
        <input type="button" value="Til baka" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1)"/>
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

The problem I have is that every time I load my page the telerik editor appears but I can not write into the text area.  (It looks like it were disabled)  :(

Comment: I have noticed that the position of the script registrar can make a difference. for example the editor would work inside a view called in RenderBody() but if it was in the _Layout it didn't. If i added the registrar after the layout it seemed to work for me, don't know if this will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**
Remove this line from your Layout

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/rikona/js/jquery-1.3.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You only need one version of Jquery, they are conflicting is my best bet.

Everything else looks right

---

Remove this line

```
.Value((string)ViewData["ProductDescription"])
```

You are using `EditorFor` which pulls the value out of the model. So you only need to set the value in one place. You were trying to set it in two places, in the `EditorFor` and `Value`.

If you were using just `Editor` not `EditorFor` you can use `Value`

So choose to do `EditorFor` like so:

```
@{ Html.Telerik().EditorFor(m => m.Product.Description)
    .Name("ProductCreateEditor")
    ...
    .Render(); 
}
```

Or `Editor`

```
@{ Html.Telerik().Editor()
    .Name("ProductCreateEditor")
    ...
    .Value((string)ViewData["ProductDescription"])
    .Render(); 
}
```

As John also states make sure the placement of your Telerik script is in the right place. It must be in the _Layout page at the bottom like so;

```
        @(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false).DefaultGroup(group => group.Combined(true).Compress(true)))
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you both for your answeres.  The telerik script is placed like you stated, at the bottom of the _Layout page within the body.  I also tried removing the ViewData from the Value section of the editor decleration but still the Editor is not working.  The editor appears on page load as if everything should work but for some reason I can not place my marker on the text area and start picking into the editor.  I checked Firebug and it did not throw any script errors (just to be sure).  Is it possible that this is due to some validation error or...?

Comment: I'd have to see your View that holds the editor as well as your Layout to make a more informed answer. Are you including your own jQuery scripts in the layout?

Comment: You said you removed the `ViewData` from the `Value` section... did you remove the whole `Value` section like I showed?

Comment: Yes I´m including my own scripts in my layout, wait just a sec, I´ll edit my post to show you my full layout and view.

Comment: @AlfaalfaStrange, thank you for your updated answer.  I tried removing the conflicting script but still nothing.  One thing I tried though, I changed my scriptregistrar to JQuery(true) and then I suddenly could write text into my editor.  However I could not post the content due to warnings of malicious code being injected, some sort of injection warning.  About this JQuery() guy, is that the that tells Telerik to compress all of the scripts?

Comment: @gardarvalur here's the telerik support form thread for the editor as well. There seems to be others having your issue. One of the suggestions was to remove add-ins. It looks like your jquery versions and the add-in are conflicting with Telerik working correctly

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I guess I need to look at this better  :)

Comment: No the Jquery() in the Telerik script is telling your app to use your version of jQuery or to use the Telerik version located in `Scripts/2012.1.214` So to use yours (version 1.7.2) you use jQuery(false), to use theirs you can leave jquery() off completely from the script

Comment: The Telerik version for 2012.1.214 is version 1.7.1. You are including 1.7.2 and 1.3.2 so by saying jquery(false) it will use your 1.7.2.

Comment: I suggest copying version 1.7.2 into the /Content/rikona/js/ folder and then removing the line for 1.3.2 and leaving jquery(false) in the telerik script

Comment: yes I fixed the include of the scripts and used only 1.7.2 version.  For some reason I didn't notice that I included it twice.  Anyway, I went for the EditorFor() version and it worked like a charm  :)